# Xamarin licensing issue (can I use specific component)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I saw [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919961/pdf-viewer-component-monotouch/9684501#9684501) asking for a PDF viewer for `MonoTouch`, which is just what I need.  First I tried the Xamarin code sample suggested by poupou, but this needs a lot of extra work to use.  So I decided to try [the mTouch-PDFViewer](http://mtouch-pdfreader.com/) suggested by Alex.

So I went to the download page and on to the [GitHub for this component](https://github.com/AlexanderMac/mTouch-PDFReader) and cloned the repository.  The problem is that the `Visual Studio` solution opens with a message saying I need a different license for Xamarin than I have.  I only have a [Xamarin Indie license](https://store.xamarin.com/) and am therefore not able to build this library.

Is there a way around this?  If I copied all the code into the `Xamarin Studio`, would it work then or can't I use this component at all due to licensing problems?  Will it work in the app as long as I get hold of the `dll` file or do I need the more expensive license?

I have sent an email to the support email address for the mTouch-PDFViewer asking if the `dll` is available somewhere, but I was wondering in general if the licensing limits the use of `dll`s or just the ability to compile the code.

Comment: Have you tried opening the solution file in Xamarin Studio instead?

Comment: No, I admit I haven't thought of that.  I will try it as soon as I get to my precious iMac at home (at work I do C# development on Windows).

Comment: You could try it in Xamarin Studio on Windows too.

Comment: Xamarin Studio on windows does not support iOS development

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You were correct!  I did not know that `Xamarin Studio` and `Visual Studio` could open the same solution files, but they can.  I should have thought of that, of course, but thanks anyways! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indie license does not have Visual Studio support.  An Indie license requires you to use Xamarin Studio on a Mac.  There should not be any restrictions on using specific components.

Also, for basic PDF viewing, iOS has excellent built in support, which you might try before using a 3rd party component.

Comment: +1 You are correct, there does not seem to be any restrictions on components built with another license.  I was a bit silly to think that.  I am unlikely to go for the build in iOS support for PDF viewing now that I have my component compiled and working though (as using it would require more work than using this 3rd party component).